# CSS font stack names in multiple character sets

Tags: css, character-encoding, fonts, multilingual

E.g. for Korean, the "Dotum" font name is also written as "돋움". Is it necessary to use a font stack such as the following:

```
body {
   font-family: "돋움", "Dotum", sans-serif;
}
```

This would presumably account for users who have the Korean-named version installed, but not the Romanized-name version, and vice-versa.

If this is the case, should "Dotum" fall back to "돋움" or the other way around?

EDIT for clarity:

Is it necessary to specify both the Korean-named version and the Roman-named version of a given Korean font in a font-stack? Follow up: Which version is more common?

Comment: Maybe I'm cynical, but I'd give the font-family rule twice, once without the korean name, just in case some browsers choke on the korean name and fail to parse the line at all. (This is unrelated to your problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Either way, basically the code will first check for 돋움 and then proceed with Dotum. Hence why you include sans-serif at the end, this means if it doesn't find any of the suggested fonts it will simply use any sans-serif font.

Comment: Because the fonts are the same besides their names, the most common one should come first. My question is, which is the most common? I'll edit my question to be clearer.

Comment: Well I am not Korean so I cannot tell which one is more common. You can simply include both and since they are the same font I don't see why does it matter which one is first or second?